# Not able to import numpy: AttributeError: type object 'numpy.ndarray' has no attribute '__array_function__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to import `numpy` but I am getting following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-38d4b0363d82> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas

/home/oto/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
     11 for dependency in hard_dependencies:
     12     try:
---> 13         __import__(dependency)
     14     except ImportError as e:
     15         missing_dependencies.append(dependency)

/home/oto/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py in <module>()
    140     from . import _distributor_init
    141 
--> 142     from . import core
    143     from .core import *
    144     from . import compat

/home/oto/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py in <module>()
     57 from . import numerictypes as nt
     58 multiarray.set_typeDict(nt.sctypeDict)
---> 59 from . import numeric
     60 from .numeric import *
     61 from . import fromnumeric

/home/oto/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in <module>()
   3091 from .umath import *
   3092 from .numerictypes import *
-> 3093 from . import fromnumeric
   3094 from .fromnumeric import *
   3095 from . import arrayprint

/home/oto/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in <module>()
     15 from . import numerictypes as nt
     16 from .numeric import asarray, array, asanyarray, concatenate
---> 17 from . import _methods
     18 
     19 _dt_ = nt.sctype2char

/home/oto/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in <module>()
    156     )
    157 
--> 158 _NDARRAY_ARRAY_FUNCTION = mu.ndarray.__array_function__
    159 
    160 def _array_function(self, func, types, args, kwargs):

AttributeError: type object 'numpy.ndarray' has no attribute '__array_function__'
```

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing `numpy`? Also, is this standalone or Anaconda distribution?

Comment: @amanb yes, I did. Its standalone

Comment: do you have any `numpy.py` file in your project?if yes rename it and its `.pyc` file.

Comment: @Adithya there is not numpy.py file

Comment: from the Traceback it seems the problem is with `pandas` try reinstalling `pandas`

Comment: Was it working before? If yes, have you installed any packages lately? You must also check if you have scripts names `numpy.py` or `pandas.py` anywhere in your project or system path and rename them if so. If the issue persists, I'd recommend un-installing Python and all relevant packages(if possible) and re-installing with the Anaconda distribution. It takes care of correctly resolving conflicts, configure `PATH` etc.

Comment: @amanb It was working before, but after installing a package, its not working. I have uninstalled that package but still not working.  Do I need to reinstall python and other packages as well ?

Comment: @Adithya I did, I reinstalled pandas

Comment: @KallolSamanta, I recommend re-installing Python with the Anaconda distribution if its possible. All scientific libraries like `numpy` & `pandas` come along with it and they work seamlessly. If for some reason, a package stops working because you installed another package, you can easily roll back to the previous working version with command line tools like `conda list --revisions` and `conda install --revision [revision number]`. If you are doing this, you must completely uninstall Python and other libraries first.

Comment: try doing it in a new virtual environment, install only pandas as it will install numpy also. if the import still doesn't work. reinstall python

Comment: a separate `numpy` installation  might have caused `pandas` incompatibility with that version of `numpy`. remove both and just install `pandas`. it will the install suitable version.

Comment: Which versions of `pandas` and `numpy`?  Someone else just got the same error message with a new `numpy` 1.16.

Comment: @amanb I am using ubuntu, I reinstalled python but still same problem

Comment: @hpaulj I am not able to import it, How could I know the version

Comment: Even after uninstalling numpy, when I am typing import numpy its giving same error seems like there is already some numpy installed. How to remove all site packages can anyone tell me ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.
Just run

```
rm -rf /home/oto/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy*

pip3 install numpy
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

remove the whole numpy directory and numpy disc info in the python3.6/site-packages
and type
pip3 install numpy

I just encounter the same problem today

Comment: You're repeating the answer given above.